# mlflow can't find .py file

Tags: python, mlflow

I'm trying to learn to use `mlflow` by creating a very simple project and log it.

I've tried following `mlflow`'s example and my code runs properly when running the main.py as a normal bash command.

I couldn't make it run using the `mlflow` CLI using project and a simple file.
I got the following error.

```
(rlearning) yair@pc2016:~/reinforced_learning101$ mlflow run src/main.py 
2019/05/11 10:21:41 ERROR mlflow.cli: === Could not find main among entry points [] or interpret main as a runnable script. Supported script file extensions: ['.py', '.sh'] ===
(rlearning) yair@pc2016:~/reinforced_learning101$ mlflow run .
2019/05/11 10:40:25 INFO mlflow.projects: === Created directory /tmp/tmpe26oernf for downloading remote URIs passed to arguments of type 'path' ===
2019/05/11 10:40:25 INFO mlflow.projects: === Running command 'source activate mlflow-21497056aed7961402b515847613ed9f950fa9fc && python src/main.py 1.0' in run with ID 'ed51446de4c44903ab891d09cfe10e49' === 
bash: activate: No such file or directory
2019/05/11 10:40:25 ERROR mlflow.cli: === Run (ID 'ed51446de4c44903ab891d09cfe10e49') failed ===
```

Needless to say my main has a `.py` suffix.

Is there anything wrong that causes this issue?

My main.py is:

```
import sys

import gym
import mlflow


if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
    right_percent = float(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 1.0
    with mlflow.start_run():
        obs = env.reset()
        print(env.action_space)
        action = 1  # accelerate right
        print(obs)
        mlflow.log_param("right percent", right_percent)
        mlflow.log_metric("mean score", 1)
        mlflow.log_metric("std score", 0)
```

conda_env.yaml

```
name: rlearning
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - tensorflow-gpu
  - pip:
      - mlflow
      - gym
```

MLproject

```
name: reinforced learning

conda_env: files/config/conda_environment.yaml

entry_points:
  main:
    parameters:
      right_percent: {type: float, default: 1.0}
    command: "python src/main.py {right_percent}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with conda intitialization. Just for testing I would recommend trying `--no-conda` (after making sure you pip installed all the libs before).

So try this: `mlflow run . --no-conda`